# python: read data from beautifulsoup and arrange in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to arrange the output from beautifulsoup to pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
import urllib, json

Cik = '824142'
url = 'https://api.ustals.com/v1/indicators/xbrl?indicators=EarningsPerShareDiluted,NetIncomeLoss'\
    ',Revenues,ProfitLoss,DividendsCommonStockCash,Assets,Liabilities'\
    '&frequency=q&period_type=end_date&companies={s}&token=KUNwBJE78kDQMUfoC3g'
response = requests.get(url.format(s=Cik))
page_data = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print page_data
```

The output of page data

```
    company_id,indicator_id,2011-07-30,2011-10-29,2012-04-28,2012-07-28,2012-10-27,2013-05-04,2013-08-03,2013-11-
    02,2014-02-01,2014-05-03,2014-11-01,2015-05-02,2015-08-01,2015-10-31,2016-01-30,2016-04-30,2016-07-30,2016-10-29,2017-01-28,2017-04-29,2017-07-29,2017-10-28
    1318008,Assets,343367000,357805000,378926000,418145000,438136000,416984000,450963000,465777000,443403000,454455000,499572000,505547000,457355000,441070000,414695000,422148000,432561000,453028000,426683000,447436000,468867000,496269000
    1318008,EarningsPerShareDiluted,0.08,0.45,0.14,0.07,0.4,0.08,0.16,0.39,0.89,0.09,0.54,0.09,0.11,0.36,0.48,-0.
    08,-0.03,0.43,0.72,-0.18,-0.02,0.48

1318008,Liabilities,106880000,106092000,98507000,135708000,137777000,115743000,141548000,140583000,107749000,
    130316000,155372000,141121000,152237000,141540000,117738000,132848000,152314000,163597000,119632000,141867000
    ,154362000,169686000        1318008,NetIncomeLoss,2591000,14137000,4527000,2086000,12667000,2498000,4739000,11860000,26851000,2496000,157
    27000,2770000,3213000,9653000,13149000,-2137000,-838000,10695000,18184000,-4448000,-608000,11922000
```

How to arrange it to a tidy pandas dataframe? Date as one dataframe, Assets as one dataframe, Liabilities as one dataframe and so on.

Comment: Don't underestimate Pandas - `pd.read_csv(url.format(s=Cik))` will do the trick ;-)

Comment: @MaxU eventually you can use even `pd.read_html()`

Comment: @user32185, this would be an "overkill". We need `pd.read_html()` for parsing __HTML__ tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need solution like mentioned @MaxU in comment, but also first and second column set to `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(url.format(s=Cik), index_col=[0,1])
print (df)

                                       2011-06-30    2011-09-30    2012-03-31  \
company_id indicator_id                                                         
824142     Assets                    1.863600e+08  1.822540e+08  1.847650e+08   
           DividendsCommonStockCash           NaN           NaN           NaN   
           EarningsPerShareDiluted   1.500000e-01  2.300000e-01  1.800000e-01   
           NetIncomeLoss             3.839000e+06  5.626000e+06  4.567000e+06   

                                       2012-06-30    2012-09-30    2012-12-31  \
company_id indicator_id                                                         
824142     Assets                    2.035540e+08  1.962540e+08  1.934930e+08   
           DividendsCommonStockCash           NaN           NaN           NaN   
           EarningsPerShareDiluted   3.800000e-01  2.400000e-01  3.100000e-01   
           NetIncomeLoss             9.297000e+06  6.007000e+06  7.578000e+06   

                                       2013-03-31    2013-06-30    2013-09-30  \
company_id indicator_id                                                         
824142     Assets                    1.944730e+08  2.212140e+08  2.201380e+08   
           DividendsCommonStockCash           NaN           NaN           NaN   
           EarningsPerShareDiluted   2.900000e-01  3.300000e-01  2.800000e-01   
           NetIncomeLoss             7.140000e+06  1.211900e+07  1.052200e+07   

                                       2013-12-31      ...        2015-06-30  \
company_id indicator_id                                ...                     
824142     Assets                    2.154440e+08      ...       250012000.0   
           DividendsCommonStockCash           NaN      ...               NaN   
           EarningsPerShareDiluted   1.100000e-01      ...               0.2   
           NetIncomeLoss             7.766000e+06      ...        11130000.0   

                                       2015-09-30    2015-12-31   2016-03-31  \
company_id indicator_id                                                        
824142     Assets                    2.550980e+08  2.328540e+08  236669000.0   
           DividendsCommonStockCash           NaN           NaN          0.0   
           EarningsPerShareDiluted   2.400000e-01  2.500000e-01          0.2   
           NetIncomeLoss             1.325100e+07  1.294800e+07   10806000.0   

                                       2016-06-30    2016-09-30    2016-12-31  \
company_id indicator_id                                                         
824142     Assets                    2.575270e+08  2.572770e+08  2.565300e+08   
           DividendsCommonStockCash           NaN           NaN           NaN   
           EarningsPerShareDiluted   2.700000e-01  2.900000e-01  2.400000e-01   
           NetIncomeLoss             1.434100e+07  1.568200e+07  1.254700e+07   

                                       2017-03-31    2017-06-30    2017-09-30  
company_id indicator_id                                                        
824142     Assets                    2.652830e+08  2.850110e+08  3.031380e+08  
           DividendsCommonStockCash           NaN           NaN           NaN  
           EarningsPerShareDiluted   1.900000e-01  2.600000e-01  2.800000e-01  
           NetIncomeLoss             1.021700e+07  1.379400e+07  1.471700e+07  

[4 rows x 25 columns]
```

Also is possible small data cleaning - create index from second column, remove repeating first and transpose:

```
df = pd.read_csv(url.format(s=Cik), index_col=[1]).iloc[:, 1:].T
print (df)

indicator_id       Assets  DividendsCommonStockCash  EarningsPerShareDiluted  \
2011-06-30    186360000.0                       NaN                     0.15   
2011-09-30    182254000.0                       NaN                     0.23   
2012-03-31    184765000.0                       NaN                     0.18   
2012-06-30    203554000.0                       NaN                     0.38   
2012-09-30    196254000.0                       NaN                     0.24   
2012-12-31    193493000.0                       NaN                     0.31   
2013-03-31    194473000.0                       NaN                     0.29   
2013-06-30    221214000.0                       NaN                     0.33   
2013-09-30    220138000.0                       NaN                     0.28   
2013-12-31    215444000.0                       NaN                     0.11   
2014-03-31    228719000.0                       NaN                     0.26   
2014-06-30    241652000.0                       NaN                     0.20   
2014-09-30    247509000.0                       NaN                     0.22   
2014-12-31    233117000.0                       NaN                     0.12   
2015-03-31    236759000.0                       NaN                     0.15   
2015-06-30    250012000.0                       NaN                     0.20   
2015-09-30    255098000.0                       NaN                     0.24   
2015-12-31    232854000.0                       NaN                     0.25   
2016-03-31    236669000.0                       0.0                     0.20   
2016-06-30    257527000.0                       NaN                     0.27   
2016-09-30    257277000.0                       NaN                     0.29   
2016-12-31    256530000.0                       NaN                     0.24   
2017-03-31    265283000.0                       NaN                     0.19   
2017-06-30    285011000.0                       NaN                     0.26   
2017-09-30    303138000.0                       NaN                     0.28   

indicator_id  NetIncomeLoss  
2011-06-30        3839000.0  
2011-09-30        5626000.0  
2012-03-31        4567000.0  
2012-06-30        9297000.0  
2012-09-30        6007000.0  
2012-12-31        7578000.0  
2013-03-31        7140000.0  
2013-06-30       12119000.0  
2013-09-30       10522000.0  
2013-12-31        7766000.0  
2014-03-31        9822000.0  
2014-06-30       11363000.0  
2014-09-30       12440000.0  
2014-12-31       10533000.0  
2015-03-31        8399000.0  
2015-06-30       11130000.0  
2015-09-30       13251000.0  
2015-12-31       12948000.0  
2016-03-31       10806000.0  
2016-06-30       14341000.0  
2016-09-30       15682000.0  
2016-12-31       12547000.0  
2017-03-31       10217000.0  
2017-06-30       13794000.0  
2017-09-30       14717000.0
```